# Node names disappears when user mouse hover on the node name for d3 sankey layout on edge browser windows 10

Tags: d3.js

I created sankey layout in d3. tooltips added on links and nodes as shown in given Jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n7f2dkt0/39/
Issue is Node names disappears when user mouse hover on the node name for sankey layout on edge browser.how to resolve this issue?
[screenshot for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQyJk.png)

```
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
  .data(energy.links)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

link.on("mouseover", mouseoverLink)
link.on("mouseout", mouseoutLink);

var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
  .data(energy.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
.call(drag);



node.append("rect")
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })


node.append("text")
  .attr("x", -6)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", null)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
.filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
  .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
  .attr("text-anchor", "start");

node.on("mouseover", mouseover);
node.on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

Comment: Can you maybe screenshot what you are seeing?  Just tried it in `Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0` and don't see anything strange.

Comment: attached screenshot on link "screenshot for error" in question it self

Comment: Is there any solution to this issue?